# When I try to do a https post request in node, I get a getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND error

Tags: node.js, oauth, https, instagram

The full error is this:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://api.instagram.com https://api.instagram.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
```

and my code to get just the error is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');

app.get('/oauth/ig', function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    hostname: 'https://api.instagram.com',
    path: '/oauth/access_token?client_secret=myClientSecret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1992/oauth/ig&code='+req.query.code,
    method: 'POST',
  };
  var igRequest = https.request(options, (response) => {
    res.send("response");
  });
})
```

I am using nodejs and am trying to do the Instagram OAUTH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hostname` should be *just* the host name, not including the protocol:

```
hostname: 'api.instagram.com',
```

Comment: Awesome, it works, but now it just loads forever. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the instagram API, perhaps you might ask another, separate question if you are having other issues.

Comment: The reason it "loads forever" is probably because you aren't ending the `igRequest`. Using `https.request()` requires you to explicitly call `igRequest.end()` to let node know when you've finished sending any body content in your POST request.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by mscdex, it's worth mentioning that
there are already working modules on `npm` that do that, e.g.:

- [passport-instagram](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-instagram)
- [passport-instagram-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-instagram-token)
- [instagram-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-node)

Maybe you could use one of them instead of rolling your own solution.

There is nothing wrong about rolling your own solution but if you can't get it right, sometimes it's just not worth the hassle.

Two of the modules that I recommended above are Instagram strategies for Passport, which is a de facto standard way of doing authentication in Node, with over 300 different strategies available that you can use in a unified way.

See the [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) website for more info.